# AWS Transcribe : Word to Word Synchronisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I am using stream processing to transcribe the audio to text which is working fine. Now I want to have the word to word synchronisation so that transcribe should be in sync with the audio coming in. Say at 1 sec is "Hello"  1.4sec "How"  etc

```
var st = results[0].alternatives()[0].items()[0].startTime()
var finalStart =  st.seconds
```

similarly for end time but this logic is skipping the words in between and is not synchronous. Does anyone have any pointers to deal with this. thanks